# Python error while finding greatest number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying techgig problem of finding greatest of 3 numbers. problem as follows

> You just need to take three number as input from stdin and you need to
>   find greatest of them.
>
> #### Input Format
>
> You will be taking three numbers as an input from stdin one on each line respectively.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> -100000 <= N <= 100000
>
> #### Output Format
>
> You need to print the greatest of the three numbers to the stdout.
>
> #### Sample TestCase 1
>
> Input
>
> ```
> 902
> 100
> 666
> ```

I done this

```
''' Read input from STDIN. Print your output to STDOUT '''
#Use input() to read input from STDIN and use print to write your output to STDOUT
import sys
def main():

    s=sys.stdin.read()
    s=s.split("\n")
    a=int(s[0])
    b=int(s[1])
    c=int(s[2])
    temp=0
    e=[a,b,c]
    for i in e:
        if i > temp:
            temp=i
    print(temp)

    '''if (a>b) and (a>c):
        temp = a
    elif (b>a) and (b>c):
        temp = b
    else:
        temp = c
    print(temp)'''


main()
```

It has predefined input 902, 100, 666. My code shows 902 output and expected also shows 902, but its showing failed, Why? In above code commented or non commented thing both showing failed.

Comment: What will happen if the three numbers are -1, -2, -3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong but the output says to print using the stdout: You need to print the greatest of the three numbers to the stdout. The print in python is the same as sys.stdout.write(str(99) + '\n'). Try using stdout to print the result.

```
sys.stdout.write(str(temp))
```

Comment: `print` defaults to printing to `sys.stdout` if no file is specified: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print The only difference here would be that I don't believe this inserts a newline, but that can be done using `print` by passing an `end` argument.

Comment: your answer or Carcigenicate answer i.e. 'print(temp, end = " "); both works, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`temp` is being initialized as 0, but the input allows for negative numbers. 0 will considered larger than any negative input though. This means your algorithm will fail for test cases that have negative input.

Initialize `temp` to a value smaller than the minimum allowed input:

```
temp = -100001 # One less than the minimum
```

Comment: Carcigenicate that is for general case but here all input are positive then why code failed?

Comment: @briangrey Your algorithm looks fine otherwise. I think it's failing for cases other than what you've mentioned. It probably has hidden test cases that it's failing on. Make the change and try it again.

Comment: Carcigenicate So I took temp -1000001 but also it fails, then  What should be temp or any other error?

Comment: Carcigenicate I took temp value a i.e. first value  then it should not give error, but also it gives error

Comment: @briangrey Best I could say is their verification is broken (not unheard of), or there's a niche corner case that it's failing on. What's a link to the instructions? I still hold that your code seems fine once you make the change I recommended; at least fine by the specs you listed here.

Comment: Carcigenicate there mansion to print output to STDOUT, so what is that, is that cause error ?

Comment: @briangrey `print` prints to the stdout unless you specify otherwise. Maybe try `print(temp, end = "")`; although that would be dumb if they weren't tolerating newlines.

Comment: Carcigenicate This problem is on website of techgig. can u  try by logging and then Practice-Python-Greatest of 3 with Python Problem.   Website https://www.techgig.com/practice/question/greatest-of-3-with-python/M3A3R1g2UzJMb0plM2FvWFEyNm4yTTErYkNaSnBHSi8yNTRpY05mUFVpND0=/1

Comment: @briangrey Their site is gimped on mobile unfortunately; it just sends me to the main page.

Comment: @briangrey Make sure you've set it to Python 3,as it defaults to Python 2. If you have it set to 2, it will print tuples with what you have now.

Comment: Carcigenicate NOw it shows successful with print(temp, end = " "); BUt I opened same problem in different browser with different login and it shows error !!! by the way u can try by login on above link and then go to  Practice-Python-Greatest of 3 with Python Problem.

Comment: @briangrey I found the practice question. The editor doesn't work in mobile though. I can't type into it.

Comment: Carcigenicate  print(temp, end = "");  works everywhere with different browser and different login. But can u tell me why it wasn't working with ' print(temp)' and works with 'print(temp, end = ""); '

Comment: @briangrey `print` inserts a newline at the end by default. `end = ""` tells it not to add anything at the end. That's really stupid of the site to disallow newlines and not tell you that in the spec though.

Comment: Carcigenicate Ha ha, Thank you!!.

Answer (score 0):

Actually they are looking for the output as mentioned and though the logic of your code is right but the output will give a new line which will be considered wrong. To fix this we use within print statement (`end = ""`)
so the right code becomes

[image: code screen shot]

Hope it helps, keep coding.